# why my react hook state only update after two clicks

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './mobileNavBar.scss'
import { div } from 'react-router-dom'
import URL from '../../constant/urls'
import { openMobileMenu } from 'component/sideMenu/action/sideMenuAction'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import classnames from 'classnames'

const MobileNavBar = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        home: true,
        cat: false,
        checkout: false,
    })
    useEffect(() => {
        detectLink()
    }, [])
    const detectLink = () => {
        const path = window.location.pathname
        if (path == '/') {
            setState((current) => ({
                ...current,
                home: true,
                cat: false,
                checkout: false,
            }))
            return
        }
        if (path.includes('cat')) {
            setState((current) => ({
                ...current,
                home: false,
                cat: true,
                checkout: false,
            }))
            return
        }
        if (path.includes('checkout')) {
            setState((current) => ({
                ...current,
                home: false,
                cat: false,
                checkout: true,
            }))
            return
        }
    }
    const handleClick = () => {
        detectLink()
    }
    const homecss = classnames({ active: state.home })
    const catcss = classnames({ active: state.cat })
    const checkoutcss = classnames({ active: state.checkout })
    return (
        <div className="mobileNav">
            <Link to='/' onClick={handleClick} className={'item ' + homecss}></Link>
            <Link to='/cat' onClick={handleClick} className={'item ' + catcss}></Link>
            <Link to='/checkout' onClick={handleClick} className={'item ' + checkoutcss}></Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I got a menu look like this. I want when I click the menu item, css class `active` will be assigned to the item.

problem is, one click will not make that happen, I need to double click. it seems the state is lagging, it seems it only updates when I trigger the next action.

Comment: YOu should not be passing a function to the setState which you defined. just pass the object that  you want to update. `setState({
                home: false,
                cat: false,
                checkout: true})`

Comment: He is just using the `updater` version. Nothing wrong with that

Comment: How are you changing `pathname` uppon click?

Comment: react router do the routing.

Comment: actually the div are Links. let me update the code to reflect real code

Comment: Please do that.

Comment: What happens when you first click on a different route and the second click is on a different route like clicking on route `/`  and next clicking on route .`/cat` ?

Comment: Does it has any effect on setting the active clase to either links?

Comment: yes it does, the link i click before will be active

Comment: Then you should look for a means in getting the useEffect to depend on the path. This is because when you click on the link its rather the link that takes over control and the handleClick only works when react-router notices that the link did not change so the second click will now take effect and trigger the handleClick. If useEffect can depend on the path then each time it changes it will auto run and things will work normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're listening for changes in `pathname` which isn't immediately updated after click on `Link`. Wrap your component with `withRouter` and listen for changes in `location.pathname`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
export const NavMenu = withRouter(({ location, history, match }) =>{
    useEffect(() => detectLink(), [location])
})
```

And inside `detectLink`

```
const detectLink = () => {
    const path = location.pathname
    if (path == '/') {
        setState((current) => ({
            ...current,
            home: true,
            cat: false,
            checkout: false,
        }))
        return
    }
    if (path.includes('cat')) {
        setState((current) => ({
            ...current,
            home: false,
            cat: true,
            checkout: false,
        }))
        return
    }
    if (path.includes('checkout')) {
        setState((current) => ({
            ...current,
            home: false,
            cat: false,
            checkout: true,
        }))
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `window.location.pathname` is not updated before the render.  But there's a lot wrong w/ this code.  Your useEffect has a lot of dependencies that you're not declaring.

What I'd do is move detectLink to inside the effect, and have it run whenever `window.location.pathname` has changed.  Then change your onClick to deal with the routing (wherever that code is, since it isn't in this example)

ETA:

```
useEffect(() => {

    const detectLink = () => {
        const path = window.location.pathname
        if (path == '/') {
            setState((current) => ({
                ...current,
                home: true,
                cat: false,
                checkout: false,
            }))
            return
        }
        if (path.includes('cat')) {
            setState((current) => ({
                ...current,
                home: false,
                cat: true,
                checkout: false,
            }))
            return
        }
        if (path.includes('checkout')) {
            setState((current) => ({
                ...current,
                home: false,
                cat: false,
                checkout: true,
            }))
            return
        }
    }

    detectLink()
}, [window.location.pathname])
```

Then remove your click handler, since this will now run whenever the location changes since you're using Links